# From SDP to EVP

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

How to transform the **semidefinite program** (SDP)
$$
\min \, \, c^T x
$$
$$
\text{subject to}\,\, F(x)>0
$$
where $F>0$ is a LMI  ($F(x)=F_0 +\sum_{i=1}^n x_iF_i(x)$, $F_i$ symmetric matrix) and $c$ is a vector of $R^n$,
into the **eigenvalue problem** (EVP)
$$
\min \, \, \lambda
$$
$$
\text{subject to}\,\, \lambda Id - A(x) >0 \quad B(x)>0
$$
where A,B are symmetric matrices which depend affinely on x.

This problem comes from page 10 of [Linear Matrix Inequalities in System and Control Theory](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/lmibook/lmibook.pdf):

---

[image]